# Google fonts - Getting a list of available fonts through ajax?

Tags: ajax, list, fonts, google-font-api

I need to get a list of all available fonts on Google Fonts and display them in a dropdown, but i'm having trouble understanding the doc for Google Fonts.

Here's what i got so far.

When i go to this in the web browser i get a json response with all fonts, as expected:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?sort=popularity&key={my-key-here}
```

But when i ajax it, i get this in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?sort=popularity&key={my-key-here}. Origin {domain} is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

By the way, i'm using jQuery. Tried both `$.ajax` and `$.getJSON`.

After a bit of googling i realized maybe i need to use the [webfont loader](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader) to retreive the list? Alright, fair enough. So i added the script to the page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js"></script>
```

But then what? The API only seem to allow getting and applying specific fonts, it doesn't actually return any data, does it?

Can anyone point me in the right direction or show me how to make the request? Parsing the returned data and handling it afterwards is no big deal, but i just can't figure out how to actually *get* the data.

Comment: http://vivekdragon.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/google-font-api-for-select/ this tutorial might help you

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've had the same problem, opening the URL itself in a new window works fine, but it doesn't work as ajax request.

Your ajax/json request is correct:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key={my-key-here}
```

And you **don't** need to add this line:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js"></script>`

*Seems like you get nothing **because of google servers**, not your code. If you newly created an API key or you recently activated your webfont service, **give it few minutes**, you will be able to use your webfont service soon*

Just to confirm it for you, try the below JSON request, it works perfectly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=MY_API_KEY', function(response) {
        //alert('json object fetched successfully!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -4):

To retrieve the dynamic list of web fonts offered by the Google Web Fonts service, send the following request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

Source: Google Web Fonts API - Developer API